# Covariant return type on Eigen Matrix for base class method

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, polymorphism, eigen

Suppose that I have two different solvers that both will be called at run time.

- I want to call solvers' api and get resulted Eigen matrix through the base class pointer.
- The solved matrix size are selected from a few known values depending on some runtime variable. I need to use compiled time fixed size matrix in this case.

The solver derived class definitions are as follow.

```
template <int VarSize>
class SolverA : Solver {
 public:
  SolverA() {}

  bool Solve() override {
    // SolverA specific implementations.
  }
  const Eigen::Matrix<double, VarSize, 1>& solution() override {
    return solution_;
  }
 private:
  Eigen::Matrix<double, VarSize, 1> solution_;
}


template <int VarSize>
class SolverB : Solver {
 public:
  SolverB() {}

  bool Solve() override {
    // SolverB specific implementations.
  }
  const Eigen::Matrix<double, VarSize, 1>& solution() override {
    return solution_;
  }
 private:
  Eigen::Matrix<double, VarSize, 1> solution_;
}
```

Now the problem is how I can write the base class `solution()` method to get the resulted Eigen matrix, since the template parameter `VarSize` are not known in the base declaration.

```
class Solver {
 public:
  virtual bool Solve() = 0;
  // not covariant type, won't compile.
  // virtual const Eigen::VectorXd& solution() = 0;
}

constexpr int kEasyProbSize = 5;
constexpr int kHardProbSize = 20;

int main() {
  Solver* solver;

  if (GetComplexity() > 30) {
    solver = &SolverB<kHardProbSize>();
  } else {
    solver = &SolverA<kEasyProbSize>();
  }
  solver->Solve();
  std::cout << solver->solution() << std::endl;
}
```

Some thoughts:

- `Eigen::Matrix<double, VarSize, 1>` does not derive from `Eigen::VectorXd` so it cannot override.
- I also cannot use `const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>&` since there is no that derived information and virtual method won't allow template.
- I need to call from base class pointer so I cannot make the base class a template class.
- The solved `solution_` is already allocated and doesn't make sense to return a copy or converted to a dynamic size matrix.

Is this fixed size matrix getting from base class pointer even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to just store a `VectorXd solution_;` inside `Solver` itself. But if you insist on storing the actual solution vector only in the derived classes, you can have `solution()` return an `Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>` which can be created with just moving a pointer and a few integers:

```
class Solver {
 public:
  virtual bool Solve() = 0;
  // not covariant type, won't compile.
  using VecRef = Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd> const;
  virtual VecRef solution() = 0;
};


template <int VarSize>
class SolverA : public Solver {
 public:
  SolverA() {}

  bool Solve() override {
    // SolverA specific implementations.
    return true;
  }
  Solver::VecRef solution() override {
    return solution_;
  }
 private:
  Eigen::Matrix<double, VarSize, 1> solution_;
};


template <int VarSize>
class SolverB : public Solver {
 public:
  SolverB() {}

  bool Solve() override {
    // SolverB specific implementations.
    return true;
  }
   VecRef solution() override {
    return solution_;
  }
 private:
  Eigen::Matrix<double, VarSize, 1> solution_;
};
```

Godbolt demo: https://godbolt.org/z/MqaofsoK9

Comment: if I understand it correctly, a temporary `Eigen::Ref` object is returned so there is no `const` at the beginning of `VecRef` alias. but why is there a `const` at the end?

Comment: `Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd> const` and `const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>` are the same (same as `double int` vs `const int` or `const int*` vs `int const*`). Search for "East const vs. const West" if you like ...

Comment: i see. since it is returning, is it still equivalent  to `Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>` ?